# Fatal error: Cannot redeclare imagecreatefrombmp()

Tags: php, xampp

I'm working on a simple imageboard based by TinyBoard (xampp), when I try to post with image, website gives me error for some reason:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare imagecreatefrombmp() in C:\xampp\htdocs\inc\image.php on line 584

image.php:

```
[1]https://pastebin.com/xqj2NAuX
```

(584 line = 77 line)

PHP 7.2, any help?

**ANSWER:**

Just change the function name to something else on line 1:

function imagecreatefrombmp2($filename)

(from user3647971)

Comment: Dontcha just hate it when you come up with a name for a utility function of your own, and its the same name as a built-in you were unaware of ;) Usually a good editor will color code your function as a 'known function' which can alert you to those situations before you bang your head on the desk when it fatals out :D Or use namespaces and make a total mess of your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just change the function name to something else on line 1 :

```
function imagecreatefrombmp2($filename) {
```

the error warns you that a function named exactly like this has already been declared. It's a built-in php function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefrombmp.php

Comment: Worked for me too :)